# Are elements in the i'th row of a matrix "<=" the ith element of a vecotor

Tags: r, matrix, vector, comparison

I have a matrix m and a vector v1.  I want to compare the elements of each row to the corresponding element of my vector v1 to see if the are <= that one number. I tried:

```
apply(m,1,function(i) i <= v1)
```

but that ends up comparing the element each row to the entire v1 vector, which is not what I want. The entire row should be compared to 1 element of v1 one row to one element of v1.

```
set.seed(20)
matrix(sort(sample(50,25)),nrow=5)
v1 <- c(16,11,38,41,29)
```

Note the elements in each row are sorted, so if the ">" comparison for the 4th element in the ith row for example evaluated to TRUE all the elements 1:4 of that row would evaluate similarly.

The desired results for the 1st through 3rd rows comparison to v1 should evaluate to TTTFF and for the second row TTFFFF as only 3 and 11 are <= 11, the 3rd rows results TTTTF.

Comment: is it not `m <= v1`?

Comment: @Symbolix - yep, simple, matrices are filled in column order so the basic comparison should be fine.

Comment: @thelatemail - thanks for clarifying ;) was trying to figure out **why** it was wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the length of your vector is the same as the number of rows in your matrix, a simple comparison will work here

```
set.seed(20)
m <- matrix(sort(sample(50,25)),nrow=5)
v1 <- c(16,11,38,41,29)

m <= v1


#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [5,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```